# How to decode large json array in flutter

Tags: json, flutter

I have a rather large json file that I have downloaded using my flutter app from a web api that's around 200MB using

```
final response = Dio().get(uri, options: Options(responseType: ResponseType.plain));
```

(Using default Dio options also uses json decoding, resulting in an out of memory exception.
This is not directly part of my problem but maybe it helps)

Now the problem starts after obtaining the json string.
When I use jsonDecode on the response body I run out of memory. (maybe the same function Dio uses?)

`final data = jsonDecode(response.body);` this runs out of memory

The json object itself is an array with a lot of items with a format like this:

```
[
  {"data": {independent data1}},
  {"data": {independent data2}},
  ...
]
```

and i would be fine just decoding one item at a time instead of everything at once to reduce memory usage. Is there another way to do process all the items in this array? Something like

```
jsonArrayDecode(response.body, onItemDecode: (item) { /*do stuff with item */ });
```

Or do I have to write my own json reader that can sequentially decode it?

Comment: try `JsonDecoder` as a `StreamTransformer`

Comment: I wasn't sure what exactly you meant with JsonDecoder as StreamTransformer, but after some experimenting I replaced the Dio Transformer with a custom one and have the transformResponse function overwritten as
`Future transformResponse(RequestOptions options, ResponseBody response) {
    return JsonDecoder().bind(utf8.decoder.bind(response.stream)).first;
  }` and it works enough not to crash. It still is slow processing the json with the GC interruptions but maybe that's as good as it gets. Thanks for your input!

Comment: i did not mean `Dio Transformer` - i meant [Stream.transform()](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.3/dart-async/Stream/transform.html) method that takes [StreamTransformer](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.3/dart-async/StreamTransformer-class.html) as a parameter, more here: https://dart.dev/articles/archive/converters-and-codecs

Comment: something like: `Stream.value('[{"header": {"header1": -1}}, ' + '{"k1": 111, "k2": 222}, {"k3": 333}, ' * 2 + ' {"footer": 999}]')
  .transform(JsonDecoder(reviver))
  .listen((data) {
    print('=' * 64);
    print(data);
  });` - here `reviver` is used to pick individual items as they are parsed - which means that you can have in theory an infinite stream of input data and process items as they come

Comment: Hmm ok, but if use this, then the `onData` function from `listen` will only be called once when the entire list is already converted or can i use the reviver in a way that produces more outputs? or can I just leave out the listen and process the data in the reviver only? something like `response.data.stream.cast<List<int>>().transform(utf8.decoder).transform(JsonDecoder((key, value) { if (/*object is top level item*/) processItem(); return null; else return value }))`?

Comment: Thanks! I actually do have complex nested objects, but I can easily identify top level objects so that is not going to be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @pskink, I managed to solve my problem. I used the `ResponseType.stream` from Dio to get stream which can be processed using the reviver function argument from the `JsonDecoder`. I process all the data in the reviver and ignore the data in the `onData` function of the listener.

```
...
final response = await dio.get(uri,
        options: Options(responseType: ResponseType.stream);
Function reviver = (key, value) {
  if (/*value is element from top level list*/) {
    processItem(value);
    return null;
  }
  return value;
}
final completer = Completer();
response.data.stream.cast<List<int>>()
        .transform(utf8.decoder)
        .transform(JsonDecoder(reviver))
        .listen(null,  onDone: () { completer.complete(); });
await completer.future;
...
```

Comment: and how actually do you want to check if you are on the level 0 where you return `null` compared to level >0 where you return `value`?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a solution for the general case, but in my case the root objects and only the root objects have a key value pair {"object": "card"}, so I just check it exists.

Comment: ok i see, btw, use `JsonCodec(reviver: reviver).fuse(utf8)` as it results under the hood in a combined [_JsonUtf8Decoder](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/091c8559e30b764118e6cae612da4fdf0f6d7b81/sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib/convert_patch.dart#L66) which is 2 in 1 solution

Comment: I still do not get if we have no issue here. Even if we identify our "root" level items, and return null in reviver, last call to reviver will get value, which is array of nulls of size of initial huge list. I believe that array of nulls also takes lots of memory. Any thoughts ?

Comment: I would say that depends on the number of this initial huge list, but assuming the list has 1000000 elements and null value takes 8 bytes that would still take only 8MB

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is really that the data file is very large, then the problem can be solved by not storing unnecessary objects during parsing.
This will only make sense if not all of the data is needed, but only some of the data.
In this case, we are talking about filtering data `on the fly`, that is, directly during the data parsing process.

Below is a small example of how this can be implemented.

```dart
import 'package:fast_json/fast_json_selector.dart' as parser;
import 'package:fast_json/fast_json_selector.dart' show JsonSelectorEvent;

void main(List<String> args) {
  // Select users from the list by indexes [2..3] and terminate selection
  final users = <User>[];
  final level = '{} data [] 0 {}'.split(' ').length;
  final elementLevel = '{} data [] 0'.split(' ').length;
  void select(JsonSelectorEvent event) {
    final levels = event.levels;
    if (levels.length == level) {
      final index = event.levels[elementLevel - 1] as int;
      if (index >= 2 && index <= 3) {
        final map = event.lastValue as Map;
        final user = User.fromJson(map);
        users.add(user);
      }

      // Free up memory
      event.lastValue = null;
      if (users.length == 2) {
        throw const _TerminateException();
      }
    }
  }

  try {
    parser.parse(_data, select: select);
  } on _TerminateException {
    //
  }

  print(users.join(', '));
}

const _data = '''
{
   "success":true,
   "data":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "name":"Leanne Graham",
         "username":"Bret",
         "email":"Sincere@april.biz",
         "address":{
            "street":"Kulas Light",
            "suite":"Apt. 556",
            "city":"Gwenborough",
            "zipcode":"92998-3874",
            "geo":{
               "lat":"-37.3159",
               "lng":"81.1496"
            }
         },
         "phone":"1-770-736-8031 x56442",
         "website":"hildegard.org",
         "company":{
            "name":"Romaguera-Crona",
            "catchPhrase":"Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
            "bs":"harness real-time e-markets"
         }
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "name":"Ervin Howell",
         "username":"Antonette",
         "email":"Shanna@melissa.tv",
         "address":{
            "street":"Victor Plains",
            "suite":"Suite 879",
            "city":"Wisokyburgh",
            "zipcode":"90566-7771",
            "geo":{
               "lat":"-43.9509",
               "lng":"-34.4618"
            }
         },
         "phone":"010-692-6593 x09125",
         "website":"anastasia.net",
         "company":{
            "name":"Deckow-Crist",
            "catchPhrase":"Proactive didactic contingency",
            "bs":"synergize scalable supply-chains"
         }
      },
      {
         "id":3,
         "name":"Clementine Bauch",
         "username":"Samantha",
         "email":"Nathan@yesenia.net",
         "address":{
            "street":"Douglas Extension",
            "suite":"Suite 847",
            "city":"McKenziehaven",
            "zipcode":"59590-4157",
            "geo":{
               "lat":"-68.6102",
               "lng":"-47.0653"
            }
         },
         "phone":"1-463-123-4447",
         "website":"ramiro.info",
         "company":{
            "name":"Romaguera-Jacobson",
            "catchPhrase":"Face to face bifurcated interface",
            "bs":"e-enable strategic applications"
         }
      },
      {
         "id":4,
         "name":"Patricia Lebsack",
         "username":"Karianne",
         "email":"Julianne.OConner@kory.org",
         "address":{
            "street":"Hoeger Mall",
            "suite":"Apt. 692",
            "city":"South Elvis",
            "zipcode":"53919-4257",
            "geo":{
               "lat":"29.4572",
               "lng":"-164.2990"
            }
         },
         "phone":"493-170-9623 x156",
         "website":"kale.biz",
         "company":{
            "name":"Robel-Corkery",
            "catchPhrase":"Multi-tiered zero tolerance productivity",
            "bs":"transition cutting-edge web services"
         }
      },
      {
         "id":5,
         "name":"Chelsey Dietrich",
         "username":"Kamren",
         "email":"Lucio_Hettinger@annie.ca",
         "address":{
            "street":"Skiles Walks",
            "suite":"Suite 351",
            "city":"Roscoeview",
            "zipcode":"33263",
            "geo":{
               "lat":"-31.8129",
               "lng":"62.5342"
            }
         },
         "phone":"(254)954-1289",
         "website":"demarco.info",
         "company":{
            "name":"Keebler LLC",
            "catchPhrase":"User-centric fault-tolerant solution",
            "bs":"revolutionize end-to-end systems"
         }
      }
   ]
}''';

class Company {
  final String name;

  Company({required this.name});

  @override
  String toString() {
    return name;
  }

  static Company fromJson(Map json) {
    return Company(
      name: json['name'] as String,
    );
  }
}

class User {
  final String city;
  final int id;
  final String name;

  User({required this.city, required this.id, required this.name});

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '$id:$name from $city';
  }

  static User fromJson(Map json) {
    return User(
      city: json['address']['city'] as String,
      id: json['id'] as int,
      name: json['name'] as String,
    );
  }
}

class _TerminateException {
  const _TerminateException();
}
```